# A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies, samesite

I have an .net core 2.2 project and I get this warning on google chrome:

A cookie associated with a resource at http://doubleclick.net/ was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies marked `SameSite=None` if they are also marked `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

I tried to solve this by adding headers in Startup.cs (but it not work)

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
           {
               ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=Strict");

           });
```

Comment: Isn't doubleclick.net a Google Ads thing? In that case you don't have control over their cookie settings.

Comment: do you want to say that this warning is informative and does not involve any actions by the developers to solve it?

Comment: I got this error in flutter, so it also applies to flutter apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the Whois records, we can see that doubleclick.net is owned by Google: http://whois.domaintools.com/doubleclick.net.
You have Google ads on your page I guess?

There is nothing you can do to remove the warning, it is Google's job to fix their cookie settings on the cookies they serve.

Answer (score 2):

For any of these warnings, if you are not responsible for the domain then you are not responsible for updating the cookies. The DoubleClick team (at Google) will be responsible for updating the relevant code that sets the SameSite attributes for cookies from doubleclick.net.

At this point, the warnings are purely informational and are not impacting functionality. Enforcing this behaviour in stable Chrome is not scheduled until M80, currently targeted for Feb 2020.

Comment: Hi Rowan, a lot of resources say that chrome 80 will have this feature on by default on Feb 4. However I found from my tests that chrome 80 beta still doesn't block cookies. I tried to check that on 20 different machines and result is the same. I also checked chrome canary v81 and only on one machine I was able to see that cookies got blocked by default. Was there a change to plan to release it on Feb 4? Thank you.

Comment: I put together https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me so you can see if your specific browser is implementing the new defaults (all green ✔️ means it is using the new values) however for specific Chrome versions and their behaviour I would look at: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site for the launch timeline. We run experiments on beta / dev, so you need to turn on the flags to guarantee the new behaviour.